# Apache: adding javascript code to <head> of my page automatically

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I am using wamp server for my project, I ran into this weird thing : when I run my html file directly it shows no additional code but when I tried to run it using apache by keeping it in www root, it shows some weird script in `<head>` and `<body>` .

i.e : `<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//r.skimresources.com/api/?callback=skimlinksApplyHandlers&amp;data=%7B%22pubcode%22%3A%2241688X1080834%22%2C%22domains%22%3A%5B%5D%7D"></script>`

`<script src="https://streamified.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/scripts/defaultinjection.js"></script>`

What are these scripts and how  these are added to my page ? What are their consequences ?  My design also looks all messed up by these scripts. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that apache is the one adding those?
Do you see it in the source of the page or Dom inspection?

Comment: there is no script on my page, it's being added on runtime, I am running this file on localhost.

Comment: it is most likely inserted by a browsers extension.

Comment: I must have think of that, thanx man, it was an extension! Please write it in answers, so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mot likely being inserted by a browser extension. 
apache won't do anything like it without explicit request.

Answer (score 0):

Skimlinks is one of the advertising affiliate partners that WordPress.com works with to run ads on blogs. I guess your project is on wordpress.com or using wordpress.